# Unable to run Mahout 20newsgroups example under Cygwin

Tags: java, apache, mahout

I was able to verify that the input directory (under /tmp) exists with the newsgroup data. Not sure why I am getting a file not found exception.

$ sh classify-20newsgroups.sh
Please select a number to choose the corresponding task to run
1. naivebayes
2. sgd
3. clean -- cleans up the work area in /tmp/mahout-work-rsrinivasan
Enter your choice : 1
ok. You chose 1 and we'll use naivebayes
creating work directory at /tmp/mahout-work-rsrinivasan
Preparing Training Data
MAHOUT_LOCAL is not set; adding HADOOP_CONF_DIR to classpath.
no HADOOP_HOME set, running locally
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/cygwin/usr/local/mahout/examples/target/mahout-examples-0.6-job.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/cygwin/usr/local/mahout/examples/target/dependency/slf4j-jcl-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/cygwin/usr/local/mahout/examples/target/dependency/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
12/05/14 09:13:44 WARN driver.MahoutDriver: **No org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.PrepareTwentyNewsgroups.props found on classpath**, will use command-line arguments only
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: **Can't find input directory \tmp\mahout-work-rsrinivasan\20news-bydate\20news-bydate-train**
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.PrepareTwentyNewsgroups.main(PrepareTwentyNewsgroups.java:92)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
        at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:188)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to edit that script before it works on Windows. I imagine the paths are wrong for Cygwin/Windows.

Comment: I checked the paths in classify-20newsgroups.sh and mahout shell scripts, both of which point to the location of the input data. It appears that the issue is how the JVM uses the path. Since the JVM runs natively in Windows (i.e., outside cygwin) it is not clear to me how the path can be changed. I was able to get everything to work on a Mac. BTW, just ordered your book.

Comment: I got past the path issue by using cygpath -wp to convert them. Now I am getting this exception: 

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-rsrinivasan\mapred\staging\rsrinivasan431425615\.staging to 0700

I have MAHOUT_LOCAL set. I don't see why mahout in local mode is trying to use hadoop!!!

Comment: Local mode still means Hadoop, just not running in a cluster. It runs Hadoop in-process. (This is not Mahout-specific.) The permission error is usually because Windows doesn't have `chmod`. I think.

Answer (score 0):

it is probably best to run the example under a unix environment. When I was trying the oscon2011 reuters example I ran into similar issues; although I was using the git bash console for doing the work. It seems that the classification and clustering examples hdfs local to run properly.

I managed to get a virtualbox up and running using vagrant and the process was relatively straightforward. Yes it does add to the learning cycle but after some initial investment I was able to complete the reuters example in a couple of hours.

thanks
anand